# Determine splitting field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $x^3 - 2$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, roots-of-unity, splitting-field

Determine the splitting field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $x^3 - 2$

Also determine the basis over $\mathbb{Q}$ and its degree. Can I do this using only first principles?

Comment: Do you know what the roots of $x^3-2$ are?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$? I feel like $i$ must be involved, but I don't clearly see how.

Comment: No, it's not the *square* root of $2$...

Comment: The roots are $$\sqrt[3]2\;,\;\sqrt[3]2\,w\;,\;\sqrt[3]2\,w^2\;,\;\;w:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$$

Comment: *\$\omega\$${}{}$

Comment: Hint: the splitting field is not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, because this is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\sqrt[3]{2} \omega$ isn't

Comment: Theory is faster than first principles. Degree is $\le 3!$. Adjoinin $\sqrt[3]{2}$ gets us degree $3$ extension, sine $x^3-2$ is irreducible over the rationals. Not enough to split, since there are non-real roots. So degree is $\le 6$, $\gt 3$, divisible by $3$. And by degree, adding $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and *anything* new, like another of the cube roots, gets us all.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you explain to me where $ \omega$ comes from? I can't see where roots of unity happen in this polynomial.

Comment: Since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root, we can factor out $x-\sqrt[3]{2}$: $x^3 - 2 = (x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{2}^2)$

Comment: And then use the quadratic equation to find the complex roots in the second polynomial?

Comment: Well you've already been given the other roots: $\sqrt[3]{2}w, \sqrt[3]{2}w^2$. Why don't you plug them in there and convince yourself?

Comment: I can convince myself just fine. Calculators also work very well... but I'm more interested in methodology to solve other problems similar to this. Thank you for your help, the quadratic formula worked to solve for the other roots.

Comment: Not entirely unrelated question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294250/dimension-of-a-splitting-field-of-a-cubic-polynomial-over-mathbbq?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The roots of $x^3-2=0$ are $x_1=\sqrt[3]{2},$ $x_2= \sqrt[3]{2}\omega$, $x_3=\sqrt[3]{2}\omega^2$, where $\omega=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. It follows that the splitting field $K$ is 
$$K=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3})$$

Since $1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}^2$ form a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $1, i\sqrt{3}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ must be $1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}^2,i\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{2}i\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{2}^2i\sqrt{3} $.

Edit: I have used the following facts, taken from Robert Ashs excellent book [Abstract Algebra: The Basic Graduate Year](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter3.pdf):

3.1.7

Let $E/F$ be a field extension and suppose $\alpha\in E$ is algebraic over $F$. Then 
$$1, \alpha, \alpha^2, ..., \alpha^{n-1}$$
form a basis of $F(\alpha)$ over $F$, where $n=$deg Irr$(\alpha, F)$.

3.1.8

If $E/K/F$ are field extensions such that $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a basis for $E$ over $K$ and $\{\beta_j\}_{j\in J}$ is a basis for $K$ over $F$, then $\{\alpha_i\beta_j\}_{i\in I, j\in J}$ form a basis for $E$ over $F$.

Comment: What would be the Galois Group of K?

Comment: @YunusSyed It would be $S_3$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/galois-group-of-x3-2-over-mathbb-q) for example.