# Show that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[3]{10})$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

a) Show that $f(x)=x^6-2x^3-10$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Proof: Using Eisenstein's Criterion, with $p=2$, we show $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

b) Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{11}}$. Show that $|\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}|=6$.

Proof: Note that $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$. By part (a), we can conclude that $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Furthermore $|\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}|=6$.

c) Show that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[3]{10})$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$.

Proof: Note that $\beta=\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{11}}$ is also a root of $f(x)$. [Check by plugging it in $f(x)$.]
$$ \alpha \cdot \beta = \sqrt[3]{(1-\sqrt{11})(1-\sqrt{11})} = \sqrt[3]{-10} $$

- How do I get rid of the negative in my radical? **Recall $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$.**
- What combination will help me get $\sqrt{-3}$? Refer to: [Determine splitting field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $x^3 - 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400660/determine-splitting-field-k-over-mathbbq-of-the-polynomial-x3-2)

d) Show that $\sqrt[3]{10}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11})$ and conclude that $|L:\mathbb{Q}|=12$, where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{10})$. Moreover $K=L(\alpha)$ and thus $|K:\mathbb{Q}|=12$ or $36$.

- How do I show $\sqrt[3]{10}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11})$?
- Since the corresponding minimal polynomials of $\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{10}$ have degree $2,2,3$, respectively, and share no roots, $|L:\mathbb{Q}|=12$.
- $L(\alpha)= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{10})(\alpha)$. Does $\alpha$ get consumed by $\sqrt[3]{10}$ from what we shown in part (c) and the first part in (d)? Is this how we get $K=L(\alpha)$?
- How can $|K:\mathbb{Q}|=36$?

Comment: Hints: A) $(-x)^3=-x^3$. What does that tell you about cube roots? B) Show that if $\gamma$ is any root of $f(x)$ then either $\gamma^3=\alpha^3$ or $\gamma^3=\beta^3$. What do you know about complex third roots of unity?

Comment: Okay. So because $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$, I can 'get rid' of the negative. I haven't used third roots of unity in problems like this.

Comment: I would be surprised if the splitting field of $x^3-2$ has not been given as an example earlier in the course/book. What was the role the third roots of unity played in there? Or, can you find all the six complex zeros of $f(x)$?

Comment: Oh I see. This post helps explain it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400660/determine-splitting-field-k-over-mathbbq-of-the-polynomial-x3-2

Comment: Great. Feel free too compile an answer out of those pieces. That way you get more feedback on the details :-) Alternatively, at this point I don't see any harm in you editing the question and adding the next part. If it revolves around this same splitting field, it's fine I think.

Comment: Yes, the key point is that $\sqrt{-3}$ always leads up to $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ which is a cube root of unity : so you have a very powerful element in your candidate splitting field. Use it!

Comment: I updated the question with the last part. Thank you so far for your help, @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: For part d: If you know the degrees $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{11},\sqrt{-3}):\Bbb{Q}]$ and $[\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of{10}):\Bbb{Q}]$ then you can do the first two bullets with the usual trick involving the tower law. In the third bullet I think the point is that by part c) it follows that $\beta\in L(\alpha)$. The earlier parts also show that $\alpha^3\in K$, which gives you a lot of information about the possible values of $[K:L]$.

Comment: It is overkill here, but you may be interested in [this classic exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403924/11619) when pondering about the irreducibility of $x^3-\alpha$ over $K$.

Comment: Adding the following link because I strongly feel that [this more general result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133581/11619) should also be linked to whenever I link to the prime degree case. The interested reader should check out Bill Dubuque's answer. Caveat: not needed here, but definitely nice to know, and leads to a more comprehensive view of this recurring theme.

Comment: You can also observe that if $F=\mathbb {Q} (\alpha, \sqrt{-3})$ then $|F:\mathbb{Q} |=12$ (as $\alpha$ is real and of degree $6$ and $\sqrt {-3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) $). And then $K=F(\sqrt[3]{10})$ and $|K:F|=1 3$ or $|K:F|=3$.

Comment: The last comment has a typo. Please read the last statement as "$|K:F|=1$ or $|K:F|=3$".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry I haven't written it up. I had family visitng this week. I wrote something up. Hopefully it sounds good. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers for (a) and (b) are in the post.

**Proof of (c):** Note that $\beta=\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{11}}$ is also a root of $f(x)$. [Check by plugging it in $f(x)$.]

$$\alpha\cdot\beta= \sqrt[3]{(1+\sqrt{11})(1-\sqrt{11})}=\sqrt[3]{-10}=-\sqrt[3]{10}$$
Since $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $-\alpha\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt[3]{10})$.

Recall the idea of roots of unity. The roots of $f(x)$ are $x=\alpha, \omega\alpha, \omega^2\alpha$ where $\omega=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. It follows that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{-3},\sqrt[3]{10})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt[3]{10})$. Furthermore $K$ is a splitting field for $f(x)$.

**Proof of (d):** Since $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10}):\mathbb{Q}|=3$, and $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}|=4$, $\sqrt[3]{10}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11})$. (**why??**) I know we said Tower Law, but I think I need a review of it.

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11},\sqrt[3]{10})$. By Tower Law,
$$ |L:\mathbb{Q}|=|L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10})|\cdot |\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{10}):\mathbb{Q}| = 4\cdot 3 =12$$

Let $K=L(\alpha)$, if $\alpha$ is real, then just like the last part, we have
$$|K:\mathbb{Q}|=12$$
Recall the  $\alpha$ is a root of unity that, then we have 2 more roots to account more, so
$$|K:\mathbb{Q}|=12\cdot 3 = 36.$$

**Comments on the proofs will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Your answer has an issue in the final stage. One needs more analysis to figure out if $K$ is of degree 12 or 36 over rationals.

Comment: If you can prove that $\alpha\notin L$ then you can conclude that $K$ is of degree 36 over rationals. If $\alpha\in L$ then $K=L$ and is of degree 12

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is real it is sufficient to prove that $\alpha\notin \mathbb {Q} (\sqrt {11},\sqrt[3]{10})$.

Comment: If $\alpha\in\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt {11},\sqrt[3]{10})=M$ then $\beta=\sqrt[3]{1-\sqrt{11}}=-\sqrt[3]{10}/\alpha\in M$ and hence $\gamma=\alpha+\beta\in M$. But minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ is of degree $9$ over $\mathbb {Q} $. You can use this contradiction to complete the proof that $K$ is of degree 36 over $\mathbb {Q} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you elaborate on the 'why' I mention in my proof?

Comment: Regarding "why", $A=\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt{-3},\sqrt {11})$ is of degree $4$ over $\mathbb {Q} $. If $\sqrt[3]{10}$ lies in this field then $B=\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt[3]{10})$ would be a subfield. Hence by tower law $4=[A:\mathbb {Q}] =[A:B] [B:\mathbb {Q}] =3[A:B]$. But clearly $4$ is not a multiple of $3$ and we get contradiction.

Comment: This is ok for the purposes of answering the questions a-d. As Paramanand Singh pointed out, it is not yet clear that the degree of the splitting field is exactly 36. You can conclude that it is either 12 or 36, depending on whether $1+\sqrt{11}$ has a cube root in $L$ or not.

Comment: Anyway, with the aid of [Dedekind's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/11619) we see that the degree of the splitting field is at least $36$. Hence it is exactly $36$. I don't know whether there is a more elementary proof for this fact.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementing the other answer with a possibly unnecessarily high-browed argument proving that the splitting field has degree $36$. Or, equivalently, that $1+\sqrt{11}$ has no cube root in the field $L$.

The tool I use is [Dedekind's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/11619), so the argument relies on Galois theory and group actions. Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^6-2x^3-10$. Let $G$ be the Galois group of this polynomial, viewed as a subgroup of the group of permutations of the six roots, identified with $S_6$.

- Eisenstein's criterion ($p=2$) tells us that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. Therefore $G$ acts transitively on the set of roots, and hence
  $6\mid |G|$.

Let us fix a root $\alpha$ of $f$ in the splitting field $K$ (unique as a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$). Factorization of $f$ modulo different primes reveals other things about the action of $G$. I will pay particular attention to the subgroup $H=Stab_G(\alpha)$ that keeps the root $\alpha$ fixed.

- Modulo $7$ we have $f(x)=(x^3+1)(x^3+4)$. The first cubic factors fully, $x^3+1=(x+1)(x+2)(x+4)$, as the field $\Bbb{F}_7$ has three third roots of unity: $1,2,4$. On the other hand, the cubic $x^3+4$ remains irreducible modulo $7$ because the congruence $x^3+4\equiv0\pmod7$ has no integer solutions. So Dedekind tells us that $G$ contains a $3$-cycle $\sigma$. This $3$-cycle fixes three of the zeros. Because $G$ acts transitively on the set of roots, one of the conjugates of $\sigma$ in $G$ has $\alpha$ as a fixed point. It follows that $H$ contains a $3$-cycle, and hence $3\mid |H|$.
- By the orbit-stabilizer theorem $|G|=6|H|$ is thus a multiple of $18$. The other answer shows that $|G|=[K:\Bbb{Q}]\in\{12,36\}$, so we can conclude that
  $$|G|=[K:\Bbb{Q}]=36.$$

---

This was somewhat unsatisfactory in the sense that initially I needed help from a computer program. At some point this becomes necessary as eliminating alternative Galois groups becomes more and more demanding, when the degree grows (barring some special cases).

In the [thread inspired by this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214793/11619) Paramanand Singh reaches the same conclusion by a different computer aided calculation proving that an element of $K$ has a minimal polynomial of degree nine, implying $9\mid |G|$ and again eliminating $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=12$ as an alternative.

Comment: +1 there. I gather that CAS has been used for factorization modulo various primes.

Comment: Someday I hope to learn the proof of Dedekind theorem which appears to a very powerful tool.

Comment: Correct @ParamanandSingh. I succumbed to the need to use Mathematica.

Comment: Actually we don't need the modulo $53$ factorization at all. Editing...

Comment: Nor is the modulo $13$ factorization. And, like in the sister thread, modulo $7$ factorization can be worked out "by hand" - at least in retrospect. So in theory I don't need a CAS, but... :-)